Two finger Morra game probability
I'm a student studying two-finger morra game in theoretical probability.
This is the problem I am solving:
In the game of Two-Finger Morra, 2 players show 1 or 2 fingers and simultaneously guess the number of fingers their opponent will show. If only one of the players guesses correctly, they win an amount (in dollars) equal to the sum of the fingers shown by them and their opponent. If both players guess correctly or if neither guesses correctly, then no money is exchanged. Consider a specified player, and denote by X the amount of money they win in a single game of Two-Finger Morra.
(a) If each player acts independently of the other, and if each player makes their choice of the number of fingers they will hold up and the number they will guess that their opponent will hold up in such a way that each of the 4 possibilities is equally likely, what are the possible values of X and what are their associated probabilities?
I calculated the probability like this:
P(X = 0) = P(I am wrong) + P(both are right) = (1/2)^4 * 2 * 4 + (1/2)^4 * 4 = 12/16
P(X = 2) = P(both raised 1) * P(I am right) * P(opponent is wrong) = (1/2)^4 = 1/16
P(X = 3) = P(one raised 1 the other raised 2) * P(I am right) * P(opponent is wrong) = 1/2 * 1/2 * 2 * 1/2 * 1/2 = 2/16
P(X = 4) = P(both raised 2) * P(I am right) * P(opponent is wrong) = (1/2)^4 = 1/16
However some solutions say I am wrong, I wonder if you think my answer or calculations are wrong.

You're missing the fact that $\ X\ $ can be negative,  which will occur whenever you're wrong and your opponent is right.  The probability that $\ X=0\ ,$ for instance, is not
$$
P(\text{you're wrong})+P(\text{both right})
$$
but
$$
P(\text{both wrong})+P(\text{both right})\ \left(=\frac{1}{2}\right)\ .
$$
The possible outcomes, all of which have the same probability of $\ \frac{1}{16}\ ,$ and the corresponding value of your payoff $\ X\ $ are listed in the following table:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{your guess}&\text{your fingers}&\text{other's guess}&\text{other's fingers}&X\\
\hline
1&1&1&1&0\\
\hline
1&1&1&2&-3\\
\hline
1&1&2&1&2\\
\hline
1&1&2&2&0\\
\hline
1&2&1&1&3\\
\hline
1&2&1&2&0\\
\hline
1&2&2&1&0\\
\hline
1&2&2&2&-4\\
\hline
2&1&1&1&-2\\
\hline
2&1&1&2&0\\
\hline
2&1&2&1&0\\
\hline
2&1&2&2&3\\
\hline
2&2&1&1&0\\
\hline
2&2&1&2&4\\
\hline
2&2&2&1&-3\\
\hline
2&2&2&2&0\\
\hline
\end{array}
It follows that the distribution of $\ X\ $ is given by the following table:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
X&0&\pm2&\pm3&\pm4\\
\hline
\text{probability}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{16}&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{16}\\
\hline
\end{array}
This strategy of choosing randomly with equal probability from all your options is not optimal. Against an opponent who plays optimally it's guaranteed to lose money in the long run.  The optimal strategies for f-finger Morra were characterised by the mathematician I.J. Good in this paper of $1965.$  If $\ \pi_{sg}\ $ is the probability that a player shows $\ s\ $ fingers and guesses that his opponent will show $\ g\ $ fingers, then this will be optimal for f-finger Morra if and only if
$$
\pi_{sg}=0
$$
for all $\ g\ne f+1-s\ ,$ and
$$
\frac{f+2}{f+1}\le\frac{\pi_{s\,f+1-s}}{\pi_{s+1\,f-s}}\le\frac{f+1}{f}
$$
for $\ 1\le s\le f-1\ .$
Note
When a single game of Morra is played for money, anything won by a player is normally paid for by the other player or players (there are versions with more than two players). It is therefore a zero-sum game, and in a two-person version, you must lose whatever your opponent wins. This is the version of the game treated by I.J.Good in the article cited above. Since you write "If only one of the players guesses correctly, they win an amount $\color{red}{\text{(in dollars)}}$..." and "If both players guess correctly or if neither guesses correctly, then $\color{red}{\text{no}}$ $\color{red}{\text{money}}$ $\color{red}{\text{is}}$ $\color{red}{\text{exchanged}}$", I had presumed that this is the version you were intending to describe.
There are versions of Morra, however, where a match of several games is won by the first player to accumulate a certain number of points, which are awarded to any winner of a single game according to the rules you've described.  If a match of this form is played for money, then the amount of money the winner receives (and therefore lost by the other player or players) is not necessarily equal to the number of points accumulated.  But in that case the points won are not the same thing as money, and should not be referred to as such.
Judging from your comment below, it would appear that you may have intended to describe a game of this type, in which the players are awarded points rather than winning money from the other player.  In that case, your calculation gives the correct probabilities for distribution of points won by either player.
Given the ambiguity in the description of the game you've given here, you should consider the possibility that proponents of the "some solutions" you've interpreted as saying that you're wrong could well be referring to a version the game that's different from the one you're referring to.

I also thought about this one but the problem didn't imply anything about giving money :(

From the statement given in the OP, it cannot be concluded that the players will pay each other or that the money will be paid by the game host. I believe that the second impression is more likely if the reader is not already familiar with the two-finger game. It is possible that the question designer ignored the zero-sum property of the original game, as he also assumed that each player chooses each of the four options ahead with equal probability, while in the Nash equilibrium, the probability vector of each player is  $(0,7/12,5/12,0)$, not  $(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)$ (@jinjin).

Your calculation seems correct. To make sure, I enumerated all $(2\times2)\times(2\times2)$ outcomes of the game, which are equally likely, as shown in the following image, and got the same result.

$$P(\color{purple}{X=0})=\frac{\color{purple}{12}}{16},P(\color{purple}{X=1})=\frac{\color{purple}{0}}{16},P(\color{purple}{X=2})=P(\color{purple}{X=4})=\frac{\color{purple}{1}}{16}, P(\color{purple}{X=3})=\frac{\color{purple}{2}}{16}.$$
